# The method 'putIfAbsent' was called on null

Tags: list, flutter, linkedhashmap

I am trying to create a LinkedHashMap and populate it with a DateTime as the key and a List as the value in my flutter app. I keep running into problems with creating this.

Here is what I am trying right now without success:

```
List<dynamic> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day) {
    for (int i = 0; i < eventDoc.length; i++ ) {
      if (day.year == eventDate.year && day.day == eventDate.day && day.month == eventDate.month) {
        List<dynamic> eventList = [];
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].agencyId);
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].agentId);
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].eventDate);
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].eventDescription);
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].eventDuration);
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].eventName);
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].eventStartTime);
        return kEvents.putIfAbsent(eventDateUTC, () => eventList);
      }
    }
   }
```

Everything is working except the last line and the putIfAbsent call. The eventDateUTC and the eventList both have values.

I am getting this error when I try to execute the
**return kEvents.putIfAbsent(eventDateUTC, () => eventList);**
line. When this line executes I get this error:

```
The method 'putIfAbsent' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: putIfAbsent(Instance of 'DateTime', Closure: () => List<dynamic>)
```

kEvents is declared like this:
LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List> kEvents;

I am sure I am missing something small but I don't have enough experience with flutter to know what it is. Please help if you can.

Comment: `kEvents` is only declared but not assigned a value (at least not in the code you are showing us) thus, it's `null`. And that's also what the error is telling you.

Comment: kEvents is assigned after populating the list with this line, return kEvents.putIfAbsent(eventDateUTC, () => eventList);

Comment: `kEvents` is equal to `null` - thats why you have that error, simply add `print('kEvents: $kEvents');` before calling `return kEvents.putIfAbsent...` and check the logs

Comment: @pskink thanks for that. I was able to see that I needed to initialize it this way:    LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<dynamic>> kEvents = LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<dynamic>>();